# Occurence of temporary stop to a thread when other thread starts in Raspbian

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, raspbian

I used raspberry pi3, python 2.7 and OpenCV3

I have two functions:

1. `Func1()` to run Picamera
2. `Func2()` to move motor forward

My problem is : when I run `Func2()` the `Func1()` stop temporary until `Func2()` finishes, although I used separate threads for each function.

My code is:

```
def picam():

    t1=threading.thread(target=Func1())
    t1.start()
    t1.join()  

def move():
    t2=threading.thread(target=Func2())
    t2.start()
    t2.join()
```

in my GUI I have 2 button . one to call picam() and other to call move()

What is the problem? I don't need `Func1()` stop temporarily because the camera will stop temporarily also.

[image]

Comment: Do you understand what `thread.join()` does?

Comment: I will post an answer as soon as you answer my previous comment...

Comment: I try delete join() but no any change

Comment: So what do you think `join` does?

Comment: I delete t2.join() and stay t1.join()
but no thing change

Comment: @MadPhysicist
join() block main thread until thread finish.

Comment: That is exactly correct. So why are you surprised that your main thread is blocking until the function finishes?

Comment: Post code and output as text. Do not post screen shots of code please.

Comment: Also, it is spelled "forward" rather than "forword"

Comment: Also, please post the code of the functions being run. A mockup is fine, but it should reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing this answer because Threading is genuinely a difficult topic. Part of the problem, especially for beginners, is the Catch 22 of opaque terminology, which makes it very difficult to understand what the different components do if you don't already understand.

Your problem is with how you use `join`. `join` is a way to wait for a given thread to finish. So calling `t1.start()` followed immediately by `t1.join()` makes the main thread wait for `t1` to finish.

Aside from the fact that you started a couple of separate thread, your code is pretty much exactly equivalent to doing

```
Func1()
Func2()
```

in the main thread.

You should put the `join`s after both threads are started if you want them to run simultaneously:

```
t1=threading.thread(target=Func1())
t2=threading.thread(target=Func2())

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

This will create two threads, start them, and then wait until both are done.

Comment: my dear I understand what you say . please read my question carefully. I do not need startup both thread in The same time,  in my GUI (Pyqt4) I have 2 button . one to call picam() and other to call move(). I can not write
t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

Comment: @mark. In that case you have not provided nearly enough information. None of what you said above was clear from the question you wrote and without seeing the actual functions it would be very difficult to debug their behavior.

Comment: because I run function Picam() that contain Thread when user click on button. and move() when click on other button

Comment: You should probably use a different mechanism than joining in that case. Look at `Thread.isAlive` to see if you should respond to further clicks. Perhaps just disable the button when you start a thread and reenable it when the function completes. This won't help with the internal issue, but it will probably help in general.

Comment: Sure thing. Take your time.

Comment: I added picture explain how I can write sample two method contain only print() but when I call function Forword_thread(self) by click on button do not startup both. only the first function start then second Funcation